# Why is it every time i try to download something its says error

Tags: unity

I tried  to download itunes,and it worked far as loading but when i clicked on it,it said "an error while loading this archive". And it always says that everytime i try to download something.

Comment: iTunes is not available for Linux. Were you downloading it or trying to install it?? Please add details to your question.

Comment: Could you please provide what is the other `something` that give error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to open a .exe file, it's likely not going to work. Ubuntu uses different files to install software. In particular, iTunes is not developed for Ubuntu or any distribution of Linux. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/add-applications/C/installation-windows-ubuntu.html) for the difference between installing software on Ubuntu versus Windows.

To browse and install Software, check out the Software Center. More information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/).

You can browse the packages available for Ubuntu here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/.